# Is it better to create custom model or use database model to the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

At the moment I have a Comic model which gets returned to the views such as:

```
var db = new ComicEntities();
var Comic = from s in db.Comics
    .Where(i => i.Comic_Id == comicId)
    .Include(i => i.ComicAuthors)
    .Include("ComicAuthors.User")
    .Include(i => i.ComicCategories)
    .Include("ComicCategories.Category")
    //.Include(i => i.ComicAltTitles)
    .Include(i => i.Chapters)
    .Include("Chapters.Pages")
    //.Include(i => i.ComicRatings)
    .Include(i => i.ComicReviews)
    .Include("ComicReviews.ComicRating")
    .Include("ComicReviews.User")
    select s;
```

I also have an alternative which is:

```
var db = new ComicEntities();
    var Comic = from s in db.Comics
        .Where(i => i.Comic_Id == comicId)
        .Include(i => i.ComicAuthors)
        .Include("ComicAuthors.User")
        .Include(i => i.ComicCategories)
        .Include("ComicCategories.Category")
        //.Include(i => i.ComicAltTitles)
        .Include(i => i.Chapters)
        .Include("Chapters.Pages")
        //.Include(i => i.ComicRatings)
        .Include(i => i.ComicReviews)
        .Include("ComicReviews.ComicRating")
        .Include("ComicReviews.User")
        select new ComicIndexView {
            comicLeftNavigationModel = new ComicLeftNavigationModel {
                chaptersCount = s.Chapters.Count(),
                pagesCount = s.Chapters.SelectMany(i => i.Pages).Count(),
                authors = s.ComicAuthors.Select(i => i.User.UserName).ToList(),
                genres = s.ComicCategories.Select(i => i.Category.Name).ToList(),
                isAuthor = s.ComicAuthors.Where(i => i.User_Id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Any(),
                image = s.ComicImage,
                published = s.DatePublished,
                status = s.Completed,
                ratingCount = s.ComicRatings.Count(),
                ratingNumber = s.ComicRatings.Sum(i => i.Rating) / s.ComicRatings.Count()
            },
            comicIndexModel = new ComicIndexModel {
                 chapters = s.Chapters,
                 description = s.Description,
                 reviews = s.ComicReviews
             }
        };
```

I was wondering which method will give me the best performance? Does it really matter which way I put it? What would be the best method to get the best performance? Would it be better to use individual queries like `Context.ComicRatings.Where(i => i.UserId == 1)` instead of using the includes?

Comment: it all depends on your need.  If we don't have to alter the model then we just send the database model to the view.  If we have to add validation or any other customization then we create a view model for it

Comment: I would recommend making the software work before working about performance. Performance tuning can happen later, based on the actual performance issue you see (if any).

Comment: @MattBodily Modification of the view model isn't the only concern - loose coupling is also a factor. It's generally advisable for your application to be decoupled from your domain model wherever possible, which would lead you down the route of a separate view model.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The software does work, however, I like to improve what I already have. They both do what I want them to do.

Comment: Are you seeing lags? Have you tried performance testing to your expected volume of use and notice issues?  If not, with the exception of @AntP, there's no reason to change it one way or the other.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I haven't done any extensive testing as of the moment.

Comment: Mark Seeman had a pretty good write-up on this:  http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorththeMapping/

Comment: I decided to opt for the splitting route. I did it so I can split up the left navigation and the index so I can use javascript to load different pages into the body of the page without having to do another database request to get the left navigation.